# ggplot2 - Pie/Bar Chart from Multiple Columns in Data Frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like the below. I have variables three variables per observation and I would like to create a bar graph per observation for each of these three variables. However, ggplot2 doesn't appear to have a way to specify multiple columns from the same data frame. What is the correct way to graph this data?

Aiming for something similar to the image below from Wikimedia (with a graph for each observation). Source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Article_count_(en-de-fr).png

```
       x   English    German    French
Sample 1      5         10        14
Sample 2      4          4        14
Sample 3      5         10        53
```

[image]

Comment: can you show what the base plot you have looks like

Comment: Updated question to be more clear.

Comment: How does this correspond to your data-set? This is the plot of one row... Why do you have 3 rows?

Comment: @Floo0, I need a plot per row, as shown in your answer below.

Comment: so what's wrong with the answer? Why do you not accept it?

Comment: Wanted to try out the code on my end. Checks out. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know why there are 2 row's per x-value.
This makes no sense. What do you want to plot? The sum per A,B,C? The mean?

Assuming you want to take the mean: Just do

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection(
"x   A    B    C
1   5   10   14
1   4    4   14
2   5   10   14
2   4    4   14
3   5   10   14
3   4    4   14
"), header=TRUE)

dat <- aggregate(. ~ x, data=dat, mean) # instead of mean you can take your function

require(reshape2)
dat_molten <- melt(dat,"x")
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat_molten, aes(x=variable, y=value)) + 
         geom_bar(stat="identity") +
         facet_grid(.~x)
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is still the same.
just save the new data-set as `dat` and start at the line with `melt`...